# ReactJS jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/login

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I have a problem with React-route-dom Link whenever I try to use it in Navbar it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/login
    at Function.ga.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at ga.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at ga.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ga [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new r.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r (scrollspy.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (scrollspy.min.js:1)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
```

This error pops up in the console when I lunch my localhost but when I access the linked page by URL and go back to home page without doing refresh the error disappear.

I tried to use data-toggle and it didn't work.

```
<ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="mySidenav2">
  <li>
    <button
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-custom navbar-btn btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light"
    >
      <Link to="/signup" data-target="#mySidenav2">
        SIGNUP
      </Link>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-custom navbar-btn btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light"
    >
      <Link to="/login" data-target="#mySidenav2">
        LOGIN
      </Link>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My routing code:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/stats/:hashCode" component={Stats} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/thanks" component={Thanks} />
          {/* <Route path="/:hashCode" component={Signup} /> */}
          <Route path="/signup/:hashCode" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/verify/:hashCode" component={Verify} />
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not wrap your Link inside button. While clicking on it, you need to route to a component, so why wrap it inside a button. If you want your Link to look like a button, use css to style it but don't wrap it inside a button or `<li>`

Comment: I tried to remove <li> and button but it didn't work